Gathering aggregate sum of rows, group by column in second table
Having trouble with a join and grouping values.  Historically I have been able to pull sums of job sizes by client_host_name - using one table. Now we have a new table that adds a new value 'service_group' and I need to group aggregate sum totals of clients grouped by service_group.
I have 2 tables to query.
Table 1:  apt_v_nbu_job_detail

client_id   (unique id of client machine)
client_display_name  (name of client)
kilobytes  (size of image for client)
expiration_date   (date image expires)

Table 2: apt_v_server_attribute

host_id  (match with apt_v_nbu_job_detail.client_id)
service_group  (value I need to group by)

Goal is to pull the client totals (kilobytes), then group the aggregate sum of all clients per service_group.
Example:
ServiceGroup          Total_GB
Core.ACS              3,109
Core.Audit            1,234
Core.Backup           1,567




SELECT j.client_host_name, sum(j.nbr_of_files), trunc(sum(j.kilobytes)/1024/1024) as "size(GB)"
FROM apt_v_nbu_job_detail j
INNER JOIN apt_v_server_attribute sa ON j.client_id = sa.host_id
--WHERE sa.service_group IN ('Core.ACS', 'Core.Audit', 'Core.Backup', 'Core.IDM', 'Core.Provisioning', 'Core.Proxies', 'Email.Zimbra');
WHERE j.client_id in (${hosts})
AND summary_status is not null
--AND expiration_date <= sysdate
GROUP BY j.client_host_name
--GROUP BY sa.service_group
ORDER BY trunc(sum(kilobytes)/1024/1024) DESC

Currently, this just pulls all clients and their total kilobytes grouped by client name.  When I try to group by service_group it gives me "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression".
My SQL skills are BASIC at best, so this has been a challenge.
TIA
For context, this is what a 'SELECT * FROM apt_v_server_attribute' gives:
host_id host_name   service_group
300,108 netbackup.lab.example.com   Core.Backup
300,109 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-dhcp-001.lab.example.com  Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,110 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-dhcp-002.lab.example.com  Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,111 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-dh4-001.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,112 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-dh4-002.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,113 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-dh6-001.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,114 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-dh6-002.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,115 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-ldp-001.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,116 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-ldp-002.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,117 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-mgt-003.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,118 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rad-001.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,119 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rad-002.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,120 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rad-003.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,121 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rad-004.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,122 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rds-001.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,123 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rds-002.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,124 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rds-003.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,125 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rds-004.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,126 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rds-005.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,127 dc1-chatt-lab-aaa-rds-006.lab.example.com   Services.GPON.DHCP-RADIUS
300,128 prov1.lab.example.com   Core.Provisioning
300,129 mta-db.lab.example.com  Email.Zimbra


Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Set up a fiddle with some sample data and your desired result. Start with ORDER BY 3.

If you want to group by sa.service_group you need to change SELECT j.client_host_name,  to SELECT sa.service_group, 

To me, it looks as if you'll have to rearrange current query so that you

replace client_host_name with service_group in both select column list and group by clause

or, if you need both of them, use both of them in group by



Here's an example (I also added missing columns to the 1st table; you missed them).
Sample tables:
SQL> WITH
  2     apt_v_nbu_job_detail (client_id,
  3                           client_display_name,
  4                           kilobytes,
  5                           expiration_date,
  6                           nbr_of_files,
  7                           client_host_name)
  8     AS
  9        (SELECT 1, 'x', 100, SYSDATE, 1000, 'xyz' FROM DUAL
 10         UNION ALL
 11         SELECT 2, 'y', 200, SYSDATE, 3000, 'uwz' FROM DUAL),
 12     apt_v_server_attribute (host_id, service_Group)
 13     AS
 14        (SELECT 1, 'aaa' FROM DUAL
 15         UNION ALL
 16         SELECT 2, 'bbb' FROM DUAL)

Query begins here:
 17    SELECT sa.service_group,
 18           SUM (j.nbr_of_files),
 19           TRUNC (SUM (j.kilobytes) / 1024 / 1024) AS "size(GB)"
 20      FROM apt_v_nbu_job_detail j
 21           INNER JOIN apt_v_server_attribute sa ON j.client_id = sa.host_id
 22     WHERE j.client_id IN (1, 2, 3)   --($ { hosts })
 23  --         AND summary_status IS NOT NULL
 24  GROUP BY sa.service_group
 25  ORDER BY TRUNC (SUM (kilobytes) / 1024 / 1024) DESC;

SER SUM(J.NBR_OF_FILES)   size(GB)
--- ------------------- ----------
bbb                3000          0
aaa                1000          0

SQL>

If you need both columns, then modify query to:
 17    SELECT sa.service_group,
 18           j.client_host_name,
 19           SUM (j.nbr_of_files),
 20           TRUNC (SUM (j.kilobytes) / 1024 / 1024) AS "size(GB)"
 21      FROM apt_v_nbu_job_detail j
 22           INNER JOIN apt_v_server_attribute sa ON j.client_id = sa.host_id
 23     WHERE j.client_id IN (1, 2, 3)   --($ { hosts })
 24  --         AND summary_status IS NOT NULL
 25  GROUP BY sa.service_group, j.client_host_name
 26  ORDER BY TRUNC (SUM (kilobytes) / 1024 / 1024) DESC;

SER CLI SUM(J.NBR_OF_FILES)   size(GB)
--- --- ------------------- ----------
bbb uwz                3000          0
aaa xyz                1000          0

SQL>


Thank you @Littlefoot,  I was way off then!  I will give this a try.

So I tried the first example, and I have some tweaking to do. Gives me error: "The query failed to evaluate.internal failure".   One thing to note, service_group values are in the apt_v_server_attribute source, and not in apt_v_nbu_job_detail so that may be an issue.

So move it into appropriate table (use a different alias). As of error itself: it doesn't sound like an Oracle error, I can't help with that.

Even a simple group by fails validation for some reason when I use apt_v_server_attribute as source:
SELECT service_group, host_id
FROM apt_v_server_attribute
WHERE service_group is not null
GROUP BY service_group
I have a LOT to learn apparently lol  If I nix the GROUP BY it pulls the data.

Progress: This appears to be working
SELECT sa.service_group, SUM(j.kilobytes)/1024/1024 as "size(GB)"
FROM apt_v_server_attribute sa
INNER JOIN apt_v_nbu_job_detail j ON sa.host_id = j.client_id
GROUP BY sa.service_group
ORDER BY trunc(sum(j.kilobytes)/1024/1024) DESC

Here is what worked for me:
SELECT sa.service_group, 
SUM(j.kilobytes)/1024/1024 as "Total_Unexpired_Data(GB)",
SUM(CASE WHEN expiration_date BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate+30 THEN kilobytes/1024/1024 END) less_than_30,
SUM(CASE WHEN expiration_date BETWEEN sysdate+30 AND sysdate+90 THEN kilobytes/1024/1024 END) bt_30_and_90,
SUM(CASE WHEN expiration_date BETWEEN sysdate+90 AND sysdate+365.25 THEN kilobytes/1024/1024 END) bt_90_and_1yr,
SUM(CASE WHEN expiration_date BETWEEN sysdate+365.25 AND sysdate+1825 THEN kilobytes/1024/1024 END) bt_1_and_5yrs,
SUM(CASE WHEN expiration_date > sysdate+1825 THEN kilobytes/1024/1024 END) over_5yrs

FROM apt_v_server_attribute sa
INNER JOIN apt_v_nbu_job_detail j ON sa.host_id = j.client_id
WHERE client_id IN (${hosts})
AND j.summary_status IS NOT NULL
--AND start_date BETWEEN ${startDate} AND ${endDate}
--AND expiration_date > sysdate
GROUP BY sa.service_group
ORDER BY trunc(sum(j.kilobytes)/1024/1024) DESC


That's, basically, the 1st query I posted - SERVICE_GROUP in both SELECT column list and GROUP BY clause.

Yeah it took me a while to get past the strange errors in the template designer UI. After about a dozen iterations of your suggestion it finally worked.  How I will never know,  but I have the data needed now.  Thanks again!

Hahah, miracles happen from time to time :) I'm glad you made it work.
